# What does browseable in samba configuration mean?

Tags: samba, cifs, shared-folders

I tried the option `browseable=no` in my /etc/samba/smb.conf file. But after it was mounted, that share was still visible to other users through the mount point. But as from what I have learnt, setting directive `browseable=yes` will make it publicly visible and setting it to no will not make it publicly visible. But why is it visible to other users thorugh the mount  point even when I have set that directive to no?
Am I missing some concepts here? Please clarify.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

From the man page:

[browseable](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#BROWSEABLE)

> This controls whether this share is seen in the list of available shares in a net view and in the browse list.

Consider, do you also have "guest ok"?

[guest ok](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#GUESTOK)

> If this parameter is yes for a service, then no password is required to connect to the service. Privileges will be those of the guest account.
>
> This parameter nullifies the benefits of setting restrict anonymous = 2
>
> See the section below on security for more information about this option.
>
> Default: guest ok = no

If `guest ok=yes` then unauthenticated users would have the guest account privileges, which might include viewing.

Comment: I didn't include the guest ok directive. And I think it is set to "no" by default.

Comment: So how do I restrict the mounted share so that it is not visible to other users?

Comment: That's probably dependent on the permissions of your mount point. If you mount on a directory that is world readable I expect all users on that system would be able to read it.

Comment: @AyushGoyal what are the permissions on your samba mount point?

Comment: It was created by root user, so using the defaults umask value 0022, the permission on my samba mount point is 0755.

Comment: 0755 is world readable, try `chmod 0750`, assuming your valid user is either the owner or a member of the group that owns that directory. Otherwise you may need a `chown` as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
[global]
#        map to guest = Bad User
#                       'Bad User' is not a valid linux account,
#                       this option will NOT have windows prompt user
#                       if windows account name does not match a valid
#                       linux account.  Windows will respond with cannot
#                       access... their might be a problem with your network
#                       contact your administrator.
#                       will make it look like samba share is not there
#                       can be used as extra layer of security to force
#                       someone to know valid usernames on linux samba server

#        map to guest = nobody
#                       nobody is a valid but locked linux account,
#                       When the given Windows user account name does not
#                       match any valid linux account then a prompt will
#                       pop up in Windows to give user chance to enter
#                       a valid linux username/password.
#                       useful if logged in as Administrator in Windows
#                       and need to access samba shares
#                       Warning: anyone on network can go \\yourlinuxserver
#                                and will get the popup and get a chance
#                                to enter your samba shares.


[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    inherit acls = Yes

[scratch]
    create mask = 660
    directory mask = 770
    inherit acls = Yes
    path = /scratch
    read only = No
    browseable = Yes

[dataX]
    create mask = 660
    directory mask = 770
    inherit acls = Yes
    path = /data_private
    read only = No
    browseable = No
```

under the global section once you have chosen a choice for `map to guest` as the first level of authentication, then `browseable` yes/no becomes useful if you want to hide a share such that users must know the name of it.  For example if the name of my linux server on the network is `linuxserver123` then if someone goes

`\\linuxserver123`  in microsoft windows they will either get prompted or rejected based on `map to guest` then allowed in if their username/password matches.

At this point the given user will see **only their home account folder** and not the `homes` folder because `browseable = no` for `[homes]`.

And all authenticated users can see `scratch` but they will NOT see the `dataX` folder because of the `browseable` setting.

For a user to get to `dataX` or the folder `/data_private` they must do `\\linuxserver123\dataX`.  If when you do just `\\linuxserver123` in Windows and you want to see a `dataX` folder in addition to `scratch` and the one home account folder then set `browseable=yes` for `[dataX]`.

Once authenticated via Samba in linux as some given *local linux account* and with `inherit acls = yes` for a given share, then that *local linux account* must have read/write/execute permissions to access the given shared folder(s) and files.